# SQL Function: The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, function

I am trying to select all the 'Cabins' from my table which are not booked on a specific date. I am rather new to SQL, and as I understand my problem is that I can not reach the 'bookedWeeks'- table since I am selecting my 'Cabin'-table. I've tried using an INNER JOIN but I cant figure out how to make it work.

I've searched the forum for similar errors, but none really seem to fit my purpose.

It is telling me that The multi-part identifier 'bookedWeeks.cabinNr' could not be bound

```
CREATE FUNCTION showAllUnbooked (@weekToCheck integer)
    RETURNS Cabin
AS
BEGIN

RETURN
(
SELECT * FROM Cabin WHERE Cabin.CNr = bookedWeeks.CabinNr AND @weekToCheck != bookedWeeks.weekNr
)
END
GO
```

I would love some help here. 
Thanks

Comment: Did you have ''bookedWeeks'' objects in your database?

Comment: you miss bookedWeeks table in your FROM clause.

Comment: Slect * is a SQL antipattern, it should not be used in production code.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of small issues: you need `bookedWeeks` in the `from` clause, but you also need to declare what the function returns a little differently:

```
create function showAllUnbooked ( @weekToCheck integer ) returns table as
return
(
    select
        * --> should not use * - explicitly list columns instead
    from 
        Cabin 
        left outer join 
        BookedWeeks 
        on 
            Cabin.CNr = BookedWeeks.CabinNr
    where
        BookedWeeks.WeekNr = @weekToCheck
        and
        BookedWeeks.CabinNr is null
)
```

The left join means you'll get "all the cabins" initially, but will exclude records that don't have a match in `BookedWeeks`.  Further, it only checks the specified week - so it might be a little more efficient.  Finally, it's a good idea to not use * to identify the columns returned from the query.  This is mostly a maintenance issue to account for changes that could impact this function.

Comment: Also when yuo havea join, select * returns the same dat in the joined field twice which is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION showAllUnbooked (@weekToCheck integer)
    RETURNS Cabin
AS
BEGIN

RETURN
(
SELECT * 
FROM Cabin 
JOIN bookedWeeks on Cabin.CNr = bookedWeeks.CabinNr 
                 AND @weekToCheck != bookedWeeks.weekNr
)
END
Go
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take two different paths.
Use join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Cabin 
JOIN bookedWeeks on Cabin.CNr = bookedWeeks.CabinNr AND @weekToCheck != bookedWeeks.weekNr
```

Or select records from both tables with your where clause (almost your query, but added bookedWeeks to the from.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Cabin, bookedWeeks 
WHERE Cabin.CNr = bookedWeeks.CabinNr AND @weekToCheck != bookedWeeks.weekNr
```

Probably the join will perform better, but both queries will return you the same result.

Comment: Never suggest using a SQL antipattern of implicit joins.